# How to sequentially combine 2 tensorflow models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have 2 Tensorflow models both having the same architecture (Unet-3d). My current flow is:

Pre-processing -> Prediction from Model 1 -> Some operations -> Prediction from Model 2 -> Post-processing

The operations in between can be done in TF. Can we combine both the models with the operations in between to 1 TF graph such that the flow would look something like this:

Pre-processing -> Model 1+2 -> Post-processing

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply put all the code for "Prediction from Model 2" at the end of the existing code within "Prediction from Model 1"? This would require training from scratch since it's essentially a new model.What exactly are you trying to achive by merging the models?

Comment: We have multiple models and Model 1 is like a preprocessing step for all other models. It would be a bit difficult to train all the models from scratch again.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `tf.keras` functional api to achieve this, here is a toy example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('TensorFlow:', tf.__version__)

def preprocessing(tensor):
    # preform your operations
    return tensor

def some_operations(model_1_prediction):
    # preform your operations
    # assuming your operations result in a tensor
    # which has shape matching with model_2's input
    tensor = model_1_prediction
    return tensor

def post_processing(tensor):
    # preform your operations
    return tensor

def get_model(name):
    inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=[256, 256, 3])
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 1, 'same')(inp)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 1, 'same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, 1, 'same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 1, 'same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, 3, 1, 'same')(x)
    # num_filters is set to 3 to make sure model_1's output
    # matches model_2's input.
    output = tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')(x)
    return tf.keras.Model(inp, output, name=name)

model_1 = get_model('model-1')
model_2 = get_model('model-2')


x = some_operations(model_1.output)
out = model_2(x)
model_1_2 = tf.keras.Model(model_1.input, out, name='model-1+2')

model_1_2.summary()
```

Output:

```
TensorFlow: 2.1.0-rc0
Model: "model-1+2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 256, 256, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 256)     147712    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 512)     1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 64)      294976    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 3)       1731      
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 256, 256, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
model-2 (Model)              (None, 256, 256, 3)       1626371   
=================================================================
Total params: 3,252,742
Trainable params: 3,252,742
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
​
```

Comment: Thanks for this example! In my case, I have saved_model for all the models. Any idea how I merge them?

Comment: just load the model and instanciate it, then apply `tf.keras.Model(model_1.input, model_loaded, name='model-1+2')` like it was explained in the answer above